# run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cypher'

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I have a graph that I want to query. I am using py2neo to do the task. However, when I ran the query, It results in the following error even though I installed the stable release.

```
Graph.run("MATCH (a) WHERE n.name=$x RETURN n.id, labels(n)", x="Length").evaluate()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cypher'

Comment: can you post the whole code? did you initialize the Graph object properly?

Comment: I actually did not. Thanks for the comment. I am trying to print the attributes of the following node. someNode = den_kg.run("MATCH (n) WHERE n.name=$x RETURN n.id, labels(n)", x="Length").evaluate()

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `run` on the `Graph` class directly, rather than on an instance of the class. You will need to initialise a graph using something like `graph = Graph(...)` and then do a `graph.run(...)` on that instead.